# PHP date_diff returns unusual warning

Tags: php, datetime, date-math

There are many questions that were asked on `date_diff` PHP function. But mine seems a bit different as I get a rather unusual result. Below is the code I have:

```
$today = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( "now" ) );
$selectDay = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( $row->BOOKING_DATE ));
$interval = date_diff( $selectDay, $today );
```

And the result I get:

```
Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in...
```

As you see $today and $selectDay both are dates. Any suggestions?
Note: I have PHP version 5.3

Comment: it expects the class `DateTime` http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: `date` function returns string. `date_diff` expects two `DateTime`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is clear. `date_diff()` expects [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects but you are passing it strings.

```
$today     = new DateTime();
$selectDay = new DateTime($row->BOOKING_DATE);
$interval  = date_diff( $selectDay, $today );
```

Or:

```
$today     = new date_create();
$selectDay = new date_create($row->BOOKING_DATE);
$interval  = date_diff( $selectDay, $today );
```

Or:

```
$today     = new DateTime();
$selectDay = new DateTime($row->BOOKING_DATE);
$interval  = $today->diff( $selectDay );
```

Comment: You are missing a `;` for $today?

Comment: @sri Ooops. Correct. Fixed for all three examples. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: On echoing $interval I get ` Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in... `. Any idea?

Comment: Try using `var_dump()` instead of `echo`. It is an object and not a string. But if you want it formatted you need to use [`DateInterval::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Answer (score 3):

`date` returns a textual representation of a UNIX timestamp in the form of a string.

`date_diff` expects a `DateTime` object, as documented here:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Incidentally,

```
date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( "now" ) )
```

is equivalent to `date('d-m-Y')`.

Answer (score 0):

use `date_create()` function before passing in `date_diff()` function params

```
$today = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( "now" ) );
$selectDay = date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( $row->BOOKING_DATE ));
$interval = date_diff( date_create($selectDay), date_create($today) );
```